# tag creation request: [cockroachdb]

Tags: support

Hi I spent a long time writing up a question and was eventually dismayed to see "You can't post this question because you need 300 rep to create tags cockroachdb, kubernetes, port-forward".

I looked through the existing tags and none of them seemed appropriate, and I can't post the question without tags. That tells me I am on the wrong site, so I will ask my question elsewhere. But I do still request that you create a `cockroachdb` tag  :)

Comment: The "elsewhere" posted question, for reference: [How can I connect to CockroachDB from outside the Kubernetes cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403931/how-can-i-connect-to-cockroachdb-from-outside-the-kubernetes-cluster)

Comment: Your question now has an answer, and the answerer is affiliated with Cockroach Labs, according to [his profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1925481/alex-robinson). What I've found noteworthy is that he's posted a number of self-answered questions on CockroachDB "elsewhere" – not here. He might have been unaware of this site at the beginning but at this point his choice of Stack Overflow would seem to be conscious, possibly because of the bigger audience. Whatever his reasons may be, the lack of CockroachDB experts' attention here seems to correlate well with the issue you've faced.

Answer (score 1):

Your case seems legitimate, although I'd be surprised if you found somebody who could answer your questions.

*Reference material taken from [Cockroach Labs | Frequrently Asked Questions](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions.html)*

## What is CockroachDB?

> CockroachDB is a distributed SQL database built on a transactional and strongly-consistent key-value store. It scales horizontally; survives disk, machine, rack, and even datacenter failures with minimal latency disruption and no manual intervention; supports strongly-consistent ACID transactions; and provides a familiar SQL API for structuring, manipulating, and querying data.
>
> CockroachDB is inspired by Google's **Spanner** and **F1** technologies, and it's completely **open source**.

## When is CockroachDB a good choice?

> CockroachDB is well suited for applications that require reliable, available, and correct data regardless of scale. It is built to automatically replicate, rebalance, and recover with minimal configuration and operational overhead. Specific use cases include:
>
> - Distributed or replicated OLTP
> - Multi-datacenter deployments
> - Cloud-native infrastructure initiatives

## When is CockroachDB not a good choice?

> CockroachDB is not a good choice when very low latency reads and writes are critical; use an in-memory database instead.
>
> Also, CockroachDB is not yet suitable for:
>
> - Complex SQL JOINS (the feature still needs optimization)
> - Heavy analytics / OLAP